# Matrix Indexing R

Tags: r

I'm trying to index a matrix in R using this code:

```
test <- matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 2) 
test[1:10, 1]  <- 1:10
test[1:10, 2]  <- 11:20

index <- c(1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2)

answer <- test[ , index]
```

I receive a 10 x 10 matrix.  But I would like to receive a vector.

`[1]  1 12  3  4 15  6  7 18  9 20`

Any ideas?

Edit:
Also, how one could use exclusionary indexing (e.g., `-index`) to exclude values from the matrix.

`[1]  11 2  13  14 5  16  17 8  19 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `row/column` indexing to extract the element by the corresponding position.  For that we can `cbind` the row sequence with the column 'index' and get the elements.

```
test[cbind(seq_len(nrow(test)), index)]
#[1]  1 12  3  4 15  6  7 18  9 20
```

Comment: Nevermind nice work.

Comment: Nice work.  How would you alter this for exclusion indexing?  When I add a negative sign to `index`, the code crashes with error:

`Error in test[cbind(1:nrow(test), -index)] : 
  negative values are not allowed in a matrix subscript`

Comment: @Nick The `row/column` index works for positive indexing.  One option will be to use `%in%` or `setdiff` to get the index of other rows/columns separately and `cbind` get the elements.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to use setdiff() to obtain a new matrix of exclusion values.

Comment: @Nick Can you update your post with a better example and expected output so that it becomes easier to code.

Comment: @Nick In your example, it is just creating a sequence of numbers from 1:20, but suppose if it is a sample of numbers, then create another dataset with the sequence of the initial matrix, extract the elements as in the solution, and get the setdiff. i.e. `test1 <- seq_along(test);dim(test1) <- dim(test); test[setdiff(test1,test1[cbind(seq_len(nrow(test1)), index)])]`