# Indexing a matrix by a vector

Tags: r

```
m = matrix(1:10, nrow = 5, ncol = 2)
y = c(1,2,2,1,1)
```

I want a vector `v` whose `i`th element is `m[i,y[i]]`.

I thought `m[,y]` would do it, but that's clearly wrong.

Comment: It is not clear how you want to define `i`, say, the length of `v`.

Comment: How about `v <- sapply(1:nrow(m), function(x) m[x, y[x]])`

Comment: And another relevant discussion from a previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022161/matrix-indexing-r

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `cbind()` to create a matrix to be used for indexing.

```
m[cbind(seq_along(y), y)]
# [1] 1 7 8 4 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Also, since in this particular case we are selecting rows `1, 2, ..., nrow(m)`,

```
diag(m[, y])
# [1] 1 7 8 4 5
```

Comment: This is very inefficient. Let `y = sample(c(1,2), 10^6, replace=TRUE)` and `m = matrix(1:(2*10^6), nrow=10^6, ncol=2)`. `system.time(m[cbind(seq_along(y), y)]` returns the correct result in less than a second. Try doing the same example with the code above.

Comment: @rawr - arguing over milliseconds is annoying yes, but in this case `diag` pretty much kills the ability to even run this function. Matrix indexing on a 10^5 example from Joseph runs in 0.007 seconds on my ancient dual core machine. `diag` fails with a "...cannot allocate vector of size 37.3Gb". Very few people have 37Gb of ram lying around.

Comment: While I agree with your comments, not everyone is always working with matrices of size 10^5, and it never hurts to be aware of another approach.. but apparently it does hurt someone enough to downvote an answer that does solve the problem.

Comment: @rawr - I didn't downvote. Don't know who did, but it wasn't me.

Comment: @rawr - in fact this is a totally valid answer and in fact deserves an upvote. I have corrected whoever downvoted it.

Comment: @Julius, I just reread my first comment.... What a jerk (me of course)!!! I tend to get blinded by _efficiency_ from time to time and it keeps me from doing as you say _(being) aware of other approaches_. In fact, as I read this question, I was knee deep in the `rbenchmark` library (I really need to lighten up). I'm reminded of the saying _premature optimization is the root of all evil_. +1 for bringing some fresh perspective.

Comment: @Julius, My first question should be _"Is it useful?_" instead of _"Is it fast?"_. Beyond being useful, your solution is a really cool way of looking at the problem, which is another thing that the need for efficiency blinds (i.e. the ability to simply appreciate a different method). I mean heck, programming is as much an art as a means to solving a problem, which makes our craft beautiful.

Comment: @JosephWood I wish I could upvote your last two comments more than once. I have recently noticed an unpleasant tendency to focus almost exclusively on performance in SO answers, thereby neglecting other aspects that could often be more important, such as code clarity, maintainability, and compactness. Whenever a solution beats the "microbenchmark" results it seems to be automatically assumed to be superior to other solutions, and it is usually heavily upvoted. Without knowing the context, however, we can't know if performance is a relevant issue at all.